# How to understand this sentence? "The working conditions are unhealthy, if not downright dangerous."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The working conditions are unhealthy, if not downright dangerous.

Does it mean

> The working conditions are unhealthy, and probably extremely dangerous."

Comment: The conditions are either dangerous, or **if not** that, unhealthy,

Comment: The most favourable way to describe them is 'unhealthy', but they could probably be better described as dangerous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "if not" mean in the given sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/what-does-if-not-mean-in-the-given-sentence). Also [Meaning of "if not" in "if not {some trait}"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229830/meaning-of-if-not-in-if-not-some-trait), and possibly others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right.

In a disapproving context, "X if not Y", means "X and quite possibly Y, (which is worse)"

Comment: I'm not sure "in a disapproving context" should be relevant here.  *The working conditions are acceptable, **if not ideal** (which is "better").* But whereas using "acceptable" causes the entire utterance to imply ***if not*** means ***but not***, if we replace "acceptable" by "extremely good", it seems to me ***if not*** becomes somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: In an approving context, it can be ambiguous. Your example could mean "and they might be ideal", but I think it more often means "even though they are not ideal". It depends on tone of voice.

Comment: snap! (do you owe me a coke, or do I owe you? :)

Answer (score 3):

You are partially correct. However, **... is X, if not Y** is an idiom, and there is an additional meaning that is not obvious.  In your example which is a negative situation, Y is a worse thing than X.

Another example.

> This is untrue, if not a deliberate lie

This means something like:  "It is untrue, but it's probably worse and is in fact a deliberate lie".

A similar way to say this is

> This is untrue; at worst, [it is] a deliberate lie.

Note: For this idiom to work in negative situations, Y is usually a worse thing than X. However, you can also use it in a positive way, e.g.,  "... is good, if not superb", where Y is better than X.